# what is the short cut key in mysql workbench to alter stored procedure or schema panel

Tags: mysql-workbench

[image]

what is the short cut key to alter stored procedure or navigate into schema panel in MySQL work bench windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut for this type of navigation. The reason is that the tab key (which is the normal navigation key) is allowed + consumed in the SQL editor. This is usually always so in text editors. Only simple (one line) edits do not eat the tab char and hence allow to navigate by that.